# Add Portable Class Library (in DLL form) to Xamarin Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, portable-class-library, xamarin-studio

I have built a Portable Class Library with Visual Studio 2012 that will also build in Xamarin Studio. I would like to add the DLL built from that PCL (from the bin directory of the solution) to an existing (Android app) project in Xamarin Studio 5.3.

I notice that according to documentation from Xamarin, this is generally possible. For example, from [this page](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/pcl/introduction_to_portable_class_libraries/):

> The output from a PCL (ie. the resulting assembly DLL) can also be added as a reference to most projects. This makes PCL an ideal way to ship cross-platform components and libraries.

If I simply right click in the solution tree and add the file, this does not seem to be usable by the project.

What is the correct way to add this resulting DLL based on a PCL to my Xamarin project?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you look under the solution explorer on the left, you can right click on `References` and select `Edit References`. Then go to `.Net Assembly` and `Browse` to navigate to the desired *.dll file. Select the file and click `Add`.

This is the simplest way there may be more

1. Right click `References`

[image]

2. Click `.Net Assembly`

[image]

3. Choose `Browse` (at the bottom right of dialog)

[image]

Comment: In newer versions the button is  named `Browse`.

Answer (score 1):

I missed it at first too. In the bottom right of .NET Assemblies, there's a "Browse" button. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Xamarin, but I'm pretty sure that there is an option to import/add references.

Under Edit References you may select an type (.net assemblies for example), and pick your dll.

regards

Comment: hades666, Thank you. There is an Edit References, but I don't immediately see how to add a dll in this view.