# Inter Framework package references

Tags: wpf, xamarin

I develop a Xamarin project for Android, it uses Xam.plugin.audio to play sound files, and works on android.
The project which uses the audio plugin is in .net standard 2.0

I developped an .Net framework project to load in a WPF application the .net standard 2.0 project which contains the xaml file of my app.

when I build the windows wpf project, I have my direct dependency, but not the audio.dll.
the nuget package of the audio.dll contains different frameworks:

[framework of audio plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6cx4.png)

below:
Crok.wpf : .net framework references Crock.view (.net standard) , which references crok.business (.net standard) which references the audio plugin:

[project references](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObmOl.png)

I have copy local true on my Wpf
And a wpf standalone app manages to use this plugin.
The question is : How do I instruct visual studio that my .Net framework project should copy local the plugin which is indirectly referenced, and copy the correct framework version

there is a very long video which show you the problem here:

[Inter framework plugin problem](https://youtu.be/zXCDNgx9ixM)

Comment: Hi, you could have a check witht the **Xam.plugin.audio** whether supports wpf, if no it will not works in wpf.

Comment: yes wpf works with this plugin, the question is how to tell visual studio to put the dll.

Comment: You could have a try with this way:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25670152/add-portable-class-library-in-dll-form-to-xamarin-studio. But not sure whether it also works for Xamarin.WPF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to target multiple frameworks for the dependency which is used by the .NET Framework.

I made a new video with the steps [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dySPK60JadI).

Comment: That's great! Remember to mark the answer when you can and it will be helpful for others who have the same issue.